# Spotify Best Before program. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, puzzle, spotify

I am trying to answer the Spotify problem [Best Before](http://www.spotify.com/se/jobs/tech/best-before/) and my code works correctly for every test case I can think of. However, according to their servers I am wrong.

Can anyone please tell me where my code has gone wrong?

Here is my code:

```
from itertools import permutations
import datetime
import fileinput

def checkdate(d,m,y):
    """Gets possible values for day, month and year 
        and generates valid permutations of dates"""
    b = permutations([d,m,y])
    for p in b:
        try:
            yield datetime.date(p[0], p[1], p[2])
        except ValueError:
            yield None

def validvalue(a):
    return a > 0 and a <= 2999

c = raw_input()
d,m,y = c.split('/')
d,m,y = int(d), int(m), int(y)

if validvalue(d) and validvalue(m) and validvalue(y):
    valid = [x for x in checkdate(d,m,y) if x is not None]
    if valid:
        print "2" + str(min(valid))[1:]
    else:
        print "%s is illegal" % c
else:
    print "%s is illegal" % c
```

Comment: *Within minutes you will get a reply indicating whether your source code solved the problem, and if it didn't, an indication of what was wrong.* - What did they say was wrong?

Comment: They only said that it's wrong. They give no indication of what actually went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

From the problem description:

> 2000 could be given as "2000", "00" or "0"

Your code does not accept `00` or `0` as a valid year.